# how error code is returned to user program?

Tags: c, unix, assembly, operating-system, kernel

I'm looking for an answer against the implementation of Unix 6th.
http://warsus.github.io/lions-/

```
2774:                 if(u.u_error < 100) {
2775:                         if(u.u_error) {
2776:                                 ps =| EBIT;
2777:                                 r0 = u.u_error;
2778:                         }
2779:                         goto out;
2780:                 }
```

The system call's error code is returned/stored in the user struc as u_error. Then it is transferred to register r0(not the r0 in the above code snippet, but close). All these happen in the kernel mode. My question is how this error code in r0 is returned to the user mode caller, particularly, can r0 be directly accessed by user mode code? I'm not looking for details.

Comment: Several layers are involved between that piece of code and the user program. Look at similar things in Linux, they are well documented. Notably study the source code of some `libc` like http://musl-libc.org/

Comment: In the future, when you ask questions like this that require more than basic programming knowledge, you should not give them a programming language tag (e.g. C). If you do so, you put your questions before morons who are just trying to run up their SO points and who put on hold questions they cannot understand---as the moron crew did to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at trap handling code. A system switches to kernel mode by causing a trap exception.

System services are wrappers that unpack the parameters, cause a trap, then repack the parameters. The piece you are missing is the user mode wrapper that causes the trap that executes the code you copied.

Comment: I learned that the kernel returns error code to user program via the register r0. But can r0 be accessed in user mode?